# What is difference between these two?

Tags: c#

```
namespace test
{
    class testclass1
    {

        public virtual void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent class");
        }
    }
}

namespace test 
{
    class Program : testclass1
    {
        public override void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Child class");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program t = new Program();
            t.test();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Using  `Program t = new Program()` answer is "Child Class" and also while using 
`testclass1 t = new Program()` answer is same!

so what is the exact difference between these two initializations?

Comment: How much do you understand already about how virtual methods work? Changing the compile-time type of a variable doesn't affect which implementation is chosen for virtual methods... although it affects which *overload* is selected when there are multiple methods to choose from, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `t` the instance of `Program` not `TestClass` so it will always call `Program`'s implementation of the method because it is the derived class and is overriding the base method.

```
public class Base
{
  //I am virtual, this means that I can be overriden
  public virtual void MethodA()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, From Base");
  }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
  //I am Base, but with other stuff.

  //I am going to do something else with MethodA
  public override void MethodA()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, From Derived");
  }
}
```

You are essentially doing.

```
Base o = new Dervied();
```

`Derived` is a base, but it can't change from `Derived` to `Base` so the implementations of `Derived` still stand.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using here is called `inheritance`. In your case, your `Program` class inherits from  `testclass1`. Inheritance describes an is-a relationship: you are a person, `Program` is-a `testclass1`.

Because of this, you can say `testclass1 t = new Program()`. You create a variable of type `testclass1` and initialize it with a `Program`, which is a special type of `testclass1`.

One of the things you can use inheritance for is to extend or replace behavior. The `virtual` keyword in your `testclass1` class means that classes that derive from it can replace the method like you are doing with the `override` keyword in your `Program` class.

The following lines would give different results:

```
Program p = new Program();
testclass1 t = new testclass1();
t.test();
p.test();
```

This will print:

```
Child class
Parent class
```

You can however use your `Program` class as if it is a `testclass1, just as you can be treated like a person or a dog like it is an animal.